# SUMPRODUCT & ROUND

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, array

Is there a way to get the product of the array with conditions to round to the 2nd decimal place before summing?

Current formula w/o rounding:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(timecards!$H$2:$H$48692,timecards!$K$2:$K$48692*(timecards!$A$2:$A$48692=A2)*(timecards!$B$2:$B$48692=B2)*ISNUMBER(MATCH(timecards!$J$2:$J$48692,{"OT","ADDOT"},0)))*1.5
```

Comment: Which column needs to be rounded before summing? H?

Comment: H & K are the columns that the multiplication happens. That I would like rounded before the summing takes place.

Comment: Visit appropriated post here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992472/sumproduct-round).